# How to scroll my list dynamically after a certain time via code?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a ListView which is populated by SimpleAdapter. Simple adapter is stuffed using 
HashMap.

Each TextView in the List shows lyrics of a song. Suppose at current time 2 items of list
 are fully visible and 3rd is half visible and half hidden as follows:
[image]

I am using MediaPlayer to play songs. When 2nd song playback ends, I need to scroll the list
so that 3rd item of list (which is half hidden due to screen resolution) could come on top
as below:
[image]

I want to implement this scenario whe mediaPlayer is on PlaybackCompleted state i.e. when 2nd song is ended. How should i do this? I am still a bigner in android please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation i have come to know that ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position) or ListView.setSelection(int position) methods will fulfill this scenario.